# Rounding to 2 decimal places

Tags: java

help, I want the output of the program to be rounded to 2 decimal places..............................................................................................................................................................................

here is my code :

```
package javaapplication2;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class NewClass {
    public static void main(String[ ] args){

int age = 0;             
age = Integer.parseInt(
JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
null, "Enter radius of a circle: "));  

        int radius = 0;
        System.out.println("Enter radius of a circle : ");
        try
        {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            radius = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException ne)
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid radius value" );
            System.exit(0);
        }
        catch(IOException ioe)
        {
            System.out.println("IO Error :" + ioe);
            System.exit(0);
        }
        radius = 5;
        double circumference = 2 * Math.PI * radius;
        double area = Math.PI * radius * radius;

        System.out.println("Area of a circle is " + area);
        System.out.println("Perimeter of a circle is " + circumference);

        }
}
```

Comment: This is not a "here's my code, fix it for me" type site. Please isolate your problem and ask a decent question.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java

Comment: my question is :

help, I want the output of the program to be rounded to 2 decimal places

above
"""here is my code :""""

Comment: You've got a ton of code unrelated to the problem. All you need to do is post 5 lines of code that summarize the issue and then ask a specific question regarding *that code*.

Comment: Please read, [Writing the Perfect Question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) for more on how to include the useful information and exclude the chaff so that we'll have an easier time understanding your actual problem.

Comment: Please don't discourage the site's new visitors with downvotes. Constructive Criticism...Downvoting some one will discourage our friend to follow these advices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you only want to display rounded values, rather than pass it on for use in further calculations, you could use `DecimalFormat`:

```
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("0.##");
System.out.println("Area of a circle is " + format.format(area));
System.out.println("Perimeter of a circle is " + format.format(circumference));
```

Comment: @ChrisValenzuela Friend Here's an upvote from me. Don't discourage by those who are always just downvoting others

Comment: -TheNoble-Coder thanks sir, I'm a student and new to programming and to this site.. I'm glad I can still see people with positive attitudes ^_^

Comment: @ChrisValenzuela You are welcome. I remember when people did that to me when I was new here. We all are students just here to learn and help :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can apply the following:

```
public double Round2(double number) {
       return Math.rint(number*100)/100;
}
```

Comment: No, this is not truly a math rounding problem but rather a String display of numeric data problem. This is the wrong solution.